# Sort contacts with CFArraySortValues in Swift

Tags: swift, abaddressbook

In Objective-C, I'd sort an array of people as follows:

```
CFArraySortValues(mutablePeople,
                  CFRangeMake(0, CFArrayGetCount(mutablePeople)),
                  (CFComparatorFunction) ABPersonComparePeopleByName,
                  kABPersonSortByFirstName)
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to do the same in Swift. The following:

```
let ctx = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>.alloc(kABPersonSortByFirstName)

CFArraySortValues(mutablePeople, 
                  CFRangeMake(0, CFArrayGetCount(mutablePeople)), 
                  ABPersonComparePeopleByName, 
                  ctx)
```

Gives compilation error:

> Cannot invoke 'CFArraySortValues' with an argument list of type
>   '(CFMutableArray!, CFRange, (ABRecord!, ABRecord!,
>   ABPersonSortOrdering) -> CFComparisonResult,
>   UnsafeMutablePointer)'

The problem looks to be with the `ABPersonComparePeopleByName` which would be cast to a `CFComparatorFunction` in Objective-C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two alternatives that avoid `CFArraySortValues` altogether:

1. Use `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering` to retrieve the contacts already sorted:

   ```
   let people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, nil, ABPersonSortOrdering(kABPersonSortByFirstName)).takeRetainedValue() as [ABRecordRef]
   ```

   If you use `nil` for the source, it uses all sources (though that behavior is not documented).
2. Alternatively, if you have a Swift array of `ABRecordRef`, you can then use the standard Swift sort routine, using `ABPersonComparePeopleByName` for the comparison:

   ```
   var people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook).takeRetainedValue() as [ABRecordRef]
   people.sort() { ABPersonComparePeopleByName($0, $1, ABPersonSortOrdering(kABPersonSortByFirstName)) != .CompareGreaterThan }
   ```

Both of these approaches return a Swift `Array<ABRecordRef>`, which is a nice native Swift collection. For example, to print the list of the names:

```
for record in people {
    let name = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(record).takeRetainedValue()
    println(name)
}
```